# How to make more secure an Android Application , security problem .

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I am using SQLite database in my Android App and storing images is not the problem, images are storing fine inside my device gallery.

But my client wants images not to store inside the device(Mobile, Tab) for their customer's security purpose.

Is there any way to store images somewhere secure place in SQLite ? and will not be visible in a device(Mobile, Tab).

Comment: You can use Application package directory.

Comment: Follow this link 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-storage-permissions/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

Comment: @Mayank and @ Kishore i am looking into it . thanks

Comment: Why my question is not useful ? i asked a simple question

Comment: I think your question is genuine . i give upvote @RashidKalhoro

Comment: Other than SD card of device can i store images somewher else and how?